# How to carry out Durbin Watson Test on dataframe with multiple columns and missing values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with multiple columns over 4000, which present companies. I want to test for autocorrelation in the time series present in each column. In order to test the autocorrelation I want to carry out Durbin Watson test on each of the column in my dataftame.Below presents the small portion of my dataset.

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10960, 10961, 10962, 10963, 
10966, 10967, 10968, 10969, 10970, 10973, 10974, 10975, 10976, 
10977, 10980, 10981, 10982, 10983, 10984, 10987, 10988, 10989, 
10990, 10991, 10994, 10995, 10996, 10997, 10998, 11001), class = "Date"), 
    A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...ASK.PRICE = c(0.0628930817610063, 
    0.0628930817610063, 0.0628930817610063, 0.0628930817610063, 
    0.0628930817610063, 0.0628930817610063, 0.0628930817610063, 
    0.0628930817610063, 0.0628930817610063, 0.0529100529100529, 
    0.031413612565445, 0.0529100529100529, 0.0512820512820513, 
    0.0512820512820513, 0.0512820512820513, 0.0512820512820513, 
    0.0512820512820513, 0.0512820512820513, 0.0310880829015544, 
    0.0310880829015544, 0.0295566502463054, 0.0590717299578059, 
    0.0854700854700855, 0.0854700854700855, 0.0854700854700855, 
    0.0854700854700855, 0.0854700854700855, 0.0436681222707424, 
    0.0436681222707424, 0.0720720720720721), ABACUS.GROUP.DEAD...18.02.09...ASK.PRICE = c(0.0307692307692308, 
    0.0155038759689922, 0.0152671755725191, 0.0152671755725191, 
    0.0152671755725191, 0.0152671755725191, 0.0211161387631976, 
    0.0239520958083832, 0.0239520958083832, 0.0171428571428571, 
    0.0085348506401138, 0.0141843971631206, 0.0141843971631206, 
    0.0141843971631206, 0.0141843971631206, 0.0141843971631206, 
    0.0141843971631206, 0.0199146514935989, 0.0285714285714286, 
    0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 
    0.0285714285714286, 0.0285714285714286, 0.015748031496063, 
    0.0223285486443381, 0.016, 0.021978021978022, 0.00918836140888208, 
    0.0148148148148148), ABB.R..IRS....ASK.PRICE = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ABBEY.NATIONAL.DEAD...T.O.SEE.702853...ASK.PRICE = c(0.0103734439834025, 
    0.00424628450106157, 0.00630914826498423, 0.00530503978779841, 
    0.00316622691292876, 0.00788732394366197, 0.00115008625646924, 
    0.00467289719626168, 0.0011997600479904, 0.00374765771392879, 
    0.00130293159609121, 0.0026246719160105, 0.0068259385665529, 
    0.00651465798045603, 0.010752688172043, 0.004062288422478, 
    0.00256739409499358, 0.00755667506297229, 0.00520833333333333, 
    0.0040133779264214, 0.00832177531206657, 0.00828729281767956, 
    0.00136518771331058, 0.0104555638536221, 0.00149588631264024, 
    0.00448765893792072, 0.0136260408781226, 0.00573065902578797, 
    0.00917431192660551, 0.00158604282315623), ABBEY.PROTECTION.DEAD...20.01.14...ASK.PRICE = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...ASK.PRICE = c(0.04149377593361, 
    0.04149377593361, 0.04149377593361, 0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 
    0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 
    0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 
    0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 0.0401606425702811, 
    0.0408163265306122, 0.0408163265306122, 0.0408163265306122, 
    0.0408163265306122, 0.0408163265306122, 0.0408163265306122, 
    0.0408163265306122, 0.0408163265306122, 0.0408163265306122, 
    0.04149377593361, 0.04149377593361, 0.04149377593361, 0.04149377593361, 
    0.04149377593361, 0.04149377593361, 0.04149377593361), ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...ASK.PRICE = c(0.028169014084507, 
    0.0188679245283019, 0.0892857142857143, 0.0600858369098712, 
    0.0418410041841004, 0.0165289256198347, 0.0165289256198347, 
    0.0165289256198347, 0.0590717299578059, 0.0590717299578059, 
    0.0765957446808511, 0.0175438596491228, 0.0269058295964126, 
    0.0269058295964126, 0.0436681222707424, 0.0616740088105727, 
    0.0444444444444444, 0.0269058295964126, 0.062780269058296, 
    0.062780269058296, 0.062780269058296, 0.062780269058296, 
    0.073394495412844, 0.073394495412844, 0.073394495412844, 
    0.073394495412844, 0.073394495412844, 0.073394495412844, 
    0.0837209302325581, 0.0754716981132075), ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..NIL.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("Date", 
"A.G.L.SJ.INVS...LON..DEAD...13.08.15...ASK.PRICE", "ABACUS.GROUP.DEAD...18.02.09...ASK.PRICE", 
"ABB.R..IRS....ASK.PRICE", "ABBEY.NATIONAL.DEAD...T.O.SEE.702853...ASK.PRICE", 
"ABBEY.PROTECTION.DEAD...20.01.14...ASK.PRICE", "ABBEYCREST.DEAD...10.10.14...ASK.PRICE", 
"ABBOT.GROUP.DEAD...07.03.08...ASK.PRICE", "ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..FULLY.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE", 
"ABERDEEN.ASSET.MAN..NIL.PAID.23.09.05...ASK.PRICE"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I would appreciate if you help me develop a code with loop additionally taking care if the missing values.

Comment: What functions are you using for the test?

Comment: The package is car and `durbinWatsonTest(model,...)`. But honestly speaking I'm not sure how to go about it and is it the best possible form of Durbin Watson avaible.

Comment: `lapply(data, durbinWatsonTest)` should be pretty close to what you're after.

Comment: @MichaelChirico and if I want to suggest it to find the appropiate lag, any advie for that.

Comment: Please append your question with all the relevant information. Also keep in mind that this site is not about statistics per se.

Comment: you'll have to pick a method for lag selection (AIC? BIC?). My main point is you're basically going to `lapply` a test-and-extraction function to all the relevant columns.

Comment: @MichaelChirico thank you!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  sorry if the question description is vague but this is the most relevant information I can provide with.

Comment: @MichaelChirico the description might be little less but I believe there is no issue in the data I provided.